# Mongoose default transaction options

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Usually when we want to do transactions, we can specify options like the following:

```js
const transactionOptions = {
  readPreference: 'primary',
  readConcern: { level: 'local' },
  writeConcern: { w: 'majority' },
};
```

However, this is an optional parameter, so I assume that Mongoose has some defaults that will be added if no option is specified.

Does anyone know what are the defaults?

Answer (score 1):

These are default options for MongoDB transactions

```
{
  readPreference: 'primary',
  readConcern: { level: 'local' },
  writeConcern: { w: 1, j: false }
}
```

References: [Read Preference](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v3.6/core/read-preference/), [Read Concern](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/read-concern/), [Write Concern](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/global.html#WriteConcern).
You can check Type Definitions of mongoose for default values as well.